# Completely disable printing in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

How can I disable printing in Google Chrome? My searches gave back results for disabling print preview, which does not do what I want - complete and utter disabling of Chrome's ability to open any kind of print dialogue, or print anything on a local or cloud printer.

**EDIT**: My problem is this. There are no printers available at the moment, so I want to prevent Chrome from triggering its or system print dialogue. I could remove virtual printers (PDF Architect, Microsoft XPS, etc), but I'd lose printing functionality in programs which rely on them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you trying to achieve by disabling printing?

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't want those using browsers to be able to print anything. There are no printers available, and I don't want the print option to be available as well, or any browser or system dialogues to be triggered. If that's even possible, that is.

Comment: You could try [disabling the print spooler service](http://www.howto-connect.com/print-spooling-service-disable-enable-windows-10/)

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about it, but it brings into play a few problems - printing is occasionally needed in some other applications, so that's a no go. In a nutshell, everything else may print, Chrome may not.

Comment: Not a XY problem. Some people just want to have only the menu options they use. I would also like to remove Save As, Send To, and Cast, because those are options that I never use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I want to disable Chrome's ability to open any kind of print dialogue, or print anything.

This can be done using [Chrome Policies for Users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2657289?hl=en):

> You can enable or disable printing. When printing is disabled, a user
>   won’t be able to print from the Chrome menu, extensions, JavaScript
>   applications, etc.

---

#### Set Chrome policies for users

> Google Chrome user policies are not available for devices enrolled
>   with a single-app kiosk license.
>
> As a Chrome administrator for your organization, you can set policies
>   for how people use their Google Account on a Chrome device, an Android
>   device, or the Chrome browser. These policies are cloud-managed, so
>   they apply when signing in from a personal or public device. The
>   policies don't apply to users signed in as guests or with a Google
>   Account outside of your organization (such as a personal Gmail
>   account).
>
> You can also set device-level policies on corporate-managed Windows®,
>   Mac®, and Linux® computers.
>
> Android apps can run on Chrome OS on supported device models only. We
>   are constantly adding support for new devices. To allow your users to
>   run Android apps, you must enable Android apps on supported Chrome
>   devices in your organization.

...

> **Turn on Chrome Management**
>
> For Chrome user policies to work on Windows, Mac, or Linux computers,
>   Chrome Management must be turned on in your Admin console.
>
> - Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> - From the Admin console dashboard, go to Apps > Additional Google Services.
> - Next to Chrome Management, click Settings .
> - Choose ON for everyone, ON for some organizations or OFF.
> - For more detailed steps, see  Turn Chrome Management on or off.
>
> Note: If you purchased Chrome licenses, Chrome policies apply to users
>   who sign in to a managed Chrome device, even if Chrome Management is
>   turned off.

...

> **Set up user policies**
>
> Before you begin: To turn the service on or off for select groups of
>   users, put their accounts in an organizational unit.
>
> - Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> - From the Admin console dashboard, go to Device management.
> - On the left, click Chrome management.
> - Click User settings.
> - On the left, select the organization to which you want the settings to apply to.
>
>   Important: Make sure Chrome Management is turned on for this organization.
> - Make the settings you want. A lightbulb marks settings that don't apply to all devices (click the lightbulb for details).
>
>   Tip: Quickly find a setting on the User settings page by typing in Search settings at the top.
>     At the bottom, click Save.
>
>   Settings typically take effect in minutes. But they might take up to an hour to apply for everyone.

...

> **Printing**
>
> You can enable or disable printing. When printing is disabled, a user
>   won’t be able to print from the Chrome menu, extensions, JavaScript
>   applications, etc.
>
> This policy has no effect on Android apps running on Chrome OS.

Source [Chrome Policies for Users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2657289?hl=en)

Comment: This seems to be working. Kind of an overkill, but as long as it gets the job done, I'm not complaining (much :) ). Thanks.